# Hide PowerShell module's functions from auto completion

Tags: function, powershell, module, powershell-module

I use a PowerShell v6.1.1 package on a CentOS 7 server.

I would like to hide some function of a module I've created, because the end user don't have to use it. It's the functions he have to use that use the ones I want to hide.

User have to use `function1`, `function1` use `function2` but the user don't have to use function2 so I don't want to let him see `function2`.

Export-ModuleMember only hide it when using `Get-Command -Module myModule` but auto complete with tab still show every functions.

Comment: *Export-ModuleMember only hide it when using `Get-Command -Module myModule` but auto completion with tab still show every functions.* Can you provide [mcve]? I can not reproduce the issue neither on Windows PowerShell 5.1 nor on PowerShell Core 6.2.0.

Comment: You could try to explicitly define the functions to export in the `psd1` file. All other functions are not exported. It depends on how many public functions you have. Another could be to onyl use the `Verb-Noun` semantic on the public functions and use a `*-*`pattern for funciton export (in the psd1 file -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)

Comment: @Moerwald it was indeed the psd1 that had to be changed and it does exactly what I needed, thx mate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moerwald's comment gave me the right way to hide functions of module both from `Get-Command` command and tab autocomplete.

`Export-ModuleMember 'function1'` in *.psm1 file only show defined function while using `Get-Command -Module myModule` but autocomplete will allow user to use every functions from module.

`Function-ToExport= 'function1'` in *.psd1 file will make defined function the only ones useable by the end user, and those function will be able to use other function in the module that are exported.